# Unable to locate css_selector element Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button

I'm trying to find a button to click using Selenium. The portion of html containing the button is the following:

```
<button class="btn-standard call-to-action">Login</button>
```

I am trying to find it with:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("btn-standard.call-to-action")
```

And then i should execute `btn.click()`

But when i try to run the code i get this error:

```
 no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
selector","selector":"btn-standard.call-to-action"}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Let us know if the below solutions worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-standard.call-to-action")
```

You are missing a dot at the beginning of **css_selector** so it looks for an element `btn-standard` and not a class. And there is no such element as `btn-standard`

Also you can try element type with class like so:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-standard")
```

Or any mix of class and element type

Answer (score 1):

You can even use xpath:

```
btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For css selectors '.' is appended in the beginning only for class.
Can you try this:

```
       btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-standard")
```